# Is Ubuntu One be able to store RAW and AVI files?

Tags: ubuntu-one, services, file-format, files

Is Ubuntu One be able to store RAW file and AVI video format. I cant find an answer on this question on here. I have tried and none of my files were able to be copied

Answer (score 4):

You can upload any kind of file to ubuntu one it shouldn't make a difference as long as you have enough free space.